# How to call a Javascript Function which is nested inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, html, function, foreach

I'm trying to modify a plugin for adding input tags which is available [here](https://github.com/GeekLaunch/tags-input)

I've written a dumbed down version of my issue below. The pluggin searches the page for any HTML with the class 'tags-input' and creates a bunch of functions for each one found to add and remove tags.
The pluggin triggers the addTag() function whenever a keydown event is detected.

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function (el) {
  function addTag(str){
    //code here adds a tag with a certain string "str"
  }
});

addTag("some string"); //function not found!
```

I want to be able to call the addTag() function from outside the forEach loop when a link from a live search is selected.

I've tried adding listeners within the loop, however, since the links from the live search are generated from a database after the page loads the listeners don't appear to pick them up.

How can I call the addTag() function from my live search?

Similar questions did not help with this specific issue:

[Call javascript inside foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312608/call-javascript-inside-foreach-loop) - No Answer Given

[call javascript function outside foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453964/call-javascript-function-outside-foreach-loop) - Different issue as far as I can tell

Comment: Not 100% what the goal of it is. So you want to create a list of functions that you can trigger?

Comment: You cannot do this without modifying the code of the plugin. I see that some of these functions have side effects to variables outside them, but local to the `forEach` callback. You cannot call those functions, unless you modify that plugin code, and expose those functions to the outer scope.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what the ultimate goal is. It is not possible to create multiple global functions with the same name and call it once. So what you would have to do is push them to some array and loop over it.  But that would be no different than just running the loop again and calling the code. So maybe you can actually explain the problem you are trying to solve,.

Comment: One possible and obvious way to go about that is to store those functions in a variable that is outside the forEach scope.

Comment: It is impossible to call the addTag function from outside the loop without modifying the original code. Can you not add the "tags-input" class to your "live-search" elements as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something Like This, No?

I understand what you're trying to do: But to make this simple I've used a List of String Values just to represent another possible approach:

```js
//  Why not create a list of functions which correspond to each list item?
var doSomeThingFuncList = [];

["Yes","No","Maybe"].forEach(function (item) {
  // Assuming that we will create a function for each list item that must be called outside of the loop
  doSomeThingFuncList.push(
    () => {
      alert("Do Something");
    }
  );
});
// The functions we have defined inside the for-loop can now be called from outside the forEach loop through indexing the function list defined at the beginning

doSomeThingFuncList[0]();
```

Basically, knowing what function to run what index of the array you'd be able to callback these functions through events on those buttons. But I am not sure what the scenario is behind this.

Comment: I am happy to have helped Richard. :)